# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.extensions'

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-algorithms, quantum-computing-for-finance

**Environment**

**Qiskit Finance version: 0.5.0**

**Python version: Using the Qiskit Lab v1.0.0**

**Operating system: Windows 11**

Hi, technically I am new to this quantum computing stuff.
I see that an upgrade of **Qiskit to 1.0** was made, and that this pretty much removed the qiskit.extensions.
However, in the Qiskit_finance repository trying to make the tutorial, they say it runs even for this new version of Qiskit.

I am trying with tutorial **09_credit_risk_analysis.ipynb** but in this part:

```python
from qiskit_finance.circuit.library import GaussianConditionalIndependenceModel as GCI

u = GCI(n_z, z_max, p_zeros, rhos)
```

It should extract a Gaussian function previously located in qiskit_finance.circuit.library

I get the error in the title.
Is there something I need to install?

Answer (score 0):

Qiskit Finance has been updated in its [repository](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-finance) with some compatibility fixes for the recently released Qiskit 1.0, but an official release has yet to be done that contains these fixes. For now you would have to [install Qiskit Finance from source](https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-finance/getting_started.html) from the main branch there, or revert to the earlier 0.46 Qiskit.

Comment: The best is to make a virtual environment and in that venv, fix the versions of your installs like `%pip install qiskit==0.46.0` and `qiskit_finance` as well